# Validación de los campos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Quisiera modificar algunos de los campos en mi formulario para que se validen pero no se como. Se que existen varios métodos pero no los entiendo, si me pueden ayudar, gracias.

Este es mi `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from datos.models import Empleados
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select, EmailInput


class EmpleadoForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Empleados

    fields = [
        'nombre',
        'apellidos',
        'genero',
        'ci',
        'cargo',
        'email',
        'telefono',
        'documento',
        'direccion',
        'estado_civil',
        'grado_instruccion',
        'numero_de_hijos',

    ]
    widgets = {
        'nombre': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca nombre'}),
        'apellidos': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca apellidos'}),
        'genero': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Seleccione su género'}),
        'ci': TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder':'Introduzca ci', 
                'minlength':'7',
                'maxlength':'8',}),
        'cargo': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca cargo'}),
        'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca email'}),
        'telefono': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca solo numero de telefono'}),
        'direccion': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca su direccion'}),
        'estado_civil': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Estado civil'}),
        'grado_instruccion': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Grado de instruccion'}),
        'numero_de_hijos': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'number','placeholder':'Numero de hijos'}),
    }
```

Los campos que quiero validar son la C.I.: (DNI) que solo acepte datos numéricos, el campo de email para que no acepte cualquier correo solo los validos, nombre y apellidos que solo acepten letras, y cualquiera otro que me sugieran y de verdad disculpen es que no entiendo mucho aun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que te ahores algo de tiempo y sea un poco mas facil implementar lo que deseas puedes hacerlo asi:

> Archivo forms.py
>
> `from django.forms import ModelForm
>   from Datos.models import Empleados
>   class FormEmpleados(ModelForm):
>       class Meta:
>           model = Empledos
>           fields = "__all__"`
>
> > Archivo models.py
> >     
> >     `class Empleados(models.Model):
> >         nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=8, min_length=7,
> >                                   null=False, unique=True, blank=False, text_help)
> >         correo = models.EmailField()`

es decir solo tendrias que usar el form, para validar lo que debe ir dentro de cada campo como expresiones que cumplan un formato, puedes usar javascript, deja hacer un ejemplo y mandartelo

Answer (score 1):

crea un archivo `validacion.js`, luego dentro del mismo copia lo siguiente:

> function validar_empleado(formulario)
>
> {
>
> var ci = /^[0123456789]+$/;
>
> if(!carnet.test(formulario.id_ci.value)||formulario.id_ci.value.length!=8)
>
> {
>   formulario.id_ci.focus();
>   return false;
>   }
>
> }

luego en el html en donde esta el formulario pon esto:

`form name="formulario" onsubmit="return validar_empleado(formulario)"`

ah que no se olvide incluir el archivo validacion.js
`script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'validacion.js '%}"` 
con esto django valida los campo email y ci, y con el js se comprueban que los datos introducidos no sean incorrectos, espero entiendas y te sirva